# If $f$ is absolutely continuous in $[0,1]$, then is $f^2$ also absolutely continuous in $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is absolutely continuous in $[0,1]$, then is $f^2$ also absolutely continuous in $[0,1]$?

I guess $f^2(x)$ is also absolutely continuous. I tried to prove by definition, 
$$f^2(x)=f^2(a)+\int_{a}^x2f(t)f'(t)dt.$$

Is there other ways to prove this without using the definition?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems your definition of absolute continuity is that $f$ is an integral? What other characterisations of absolute continuity are known to you?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I see. We can consider $f^2(x)-f^2(y)=(f(x)+f(y))(f(x)-f(y))$ and using $f(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: Yes, that works nicely for the $$\sum \lvert F(b_i) - F(a_i)\rvert < \varepsilon\text{ if } \sum \lvert b_i - a_i\rvert < \delta$$ definition/characterisation.

Comment: @DanielFischer Exactly, Thanks for your help.